# Program that compute the multiplication table for all numbers less than or equal N in JAVA

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, methods, while-loop

How do I Write a program that compute the multiplication table for all numbers less than or equal N. Note that N is an integer read from the user.

The program will repeatedly
do that until the user enter `-1` in **JAVA**.

I don't know if i should use nested loops or a method for this, but I wrote the following uncompleted code which is giving me an infinite loop

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int N ;
    System.out.println("Enter N: " );
    N = in.nextInt();

    while ( N != -1) {
        for(int i = 1; i <= N; ++i)
        {
            for (int c = 1; c <= 10; ++c)  
                System.out.println(N + "*" + c + " = " + (N*c));
        }
    }
}
```

I want an output like this :

```
Enter an integer to print it's multiplication table, -1 to
    exit
    2
    Multiplication table of 1
    1*1 = 1, 1*2 = 2, 1*3 = 3, 1*4 = 4, 1*5 = 5, 1*6 = 6, 1*7 =
    7, 1*8 = 8, 1*9 = 9, 1*10 = 10,
    Multiplication table of 2
    2*1 = 2, 2*2 = 4, 2*3 = 6, 2*4 = 8, 2*5 = 10, 2*6 = 12, 2*7
    = 14, 2*8 = 16, 2*9 = 18, 2*10 = 20, 
    Enter an integer to print it's multiplication table, -1 to
    exit  
    -1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code runs in an infinite loop because `N` does not change within the outer `for`-loop.

You can place the prompt inside the loop, and change to a [`do-while` loop](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html) to guarantee at least 1 execution; or none if the user enters a number less than 1 (because of the outer `for`-loop).

You were also missing reference to [Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) to capture the input.

Finally, you forgot to use `i` instead of `N` in the output, otherwise the inner loop will output the same values every time.

```
import java.util.Scanner;                              // Import Scanner
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int N;
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);               // Missing Scanner
    do {                                               // Changed to do-while loop
        System.out.println("Enter N: " );
        N = in.nextInt();                              // Prompt user for N.
        for(int i = 1; i <= N; ++i)
        {
            for (int c = 1; c <= 10; ++c)
                System.out.println(i + "*" + c + " = " + (i*c)); // Use i instead of N
        }
    } while ( N != -1);
}
```

Comment: My bad, I should've clarified the output I wanted ... I will edit my question

Comment: Nested loops are okay. Creating a function just breaks your code into managable pieces that can be called repetitively.

Comment: I just edited my question and added a sample run, I hope I made it clearer to you

Comment: You should convert some of your `System.out.println` to `System.out.print` to avoid the newline at the end. You can even add an empty `System.out.println()` after (outside) each of your `for`-loops.

Answer (score 2):

Sunny Patel's answer is correct, but just to show you another way to do it:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class Multiply {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        try (Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in)) {
            int N;
            do {
                System.out.println("Enter N: " );
                N = in.nextInt();
                IntStream.range(1, N+1)
                     .forEach(i -> IntStream.range(1, 11)
                                            .forEach(j -> System.out.println(String.format("%d*%d = %d", i, j, (i*j)))));
            } while ( N != -1);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I love the addition of the [`try` with resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) in Java 7.

Comment: Yeah, It's fantastic.  I just have to remember to actually use it when I'm writing code.  I've been doing java for nearly 20 years, so I'm stuck in old habits sometimes.